# Dual Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04, Windows not able to book up

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

First time installing Linux. I appreciate any help.

Laptop is a Thinkpad x250, 8GB RAM, Intel i5, 250GB SSD. It came preinstalled with Windows 10 pro

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 everything seemed to install great. When I turn the laptop on grub menu shows Ubuntu and Windows 10. Ubuntu will boot up and run fine but Windows will either crash or display "PC/Device needs repair"

I've installed Boot Repair and ran it but it didn't fix the issue. Here is the link to the paste.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fRp7nCSy8t/

I've already verified that Ubuntu is in BIOS mode. I'm pretty sure the windows was also running legacy bios.

Comment: A preinstalled Windows 10 cannot be in legacy mode. It may be if purposely installed that way by users. That is a huge mistake for no reason at all. The obvious consequence here is that very likely you need to repair Windows (in legacy mode it'll remove Grub) then reinstall Grub in order to have a dual-boot. In UEFI mode nothing of this would happen.

Comment: Best to reinstall both systems in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drive after backing up all your data in both systems. But you cannot use a UEFI boot stanza for Windows. Os-prober should just add a standard BIOS boot mode Windows boot stanza. But Windows fast startup must be off. You have to temporarily restore Windows BIOS boot mode using your Windows repair disk or installer with repair console, fix Windows & then restore grub with Boot-Repair.